# Combining vector and bitmap graphics in a pdf

Tags: r

When plotting images or heatmaps to pdfs as in the example below they are saved as vector objects where every pixel in the image or cell in the heatmap is represented by a square. Even at modest resolutions this results in unnecessarily large files that also renders uglily on some devices. **Is there a way to make R save only the image area as a png or jpg embedded in the pdf but keep text, axes, anotations etc as vector graphics?**

I'm asking since I am often printing R graphics, sometimes on large posters, and would like to combine the best of the two worlds. Of course I could save the entire figure as a high resolution png but that would not be as elegant, or combine it manually e.g. in [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) but it is quite tedious.

```
my.func <- function(x, y) x %*% t(y)
pdf(file="myPlot.pdf")
image(my.func(seq(-10,10,,500), seq(-5,15,,500)), col=heat.colors(100))
dev.off()
```

[image: The figure generated by the above code]

Thanks for your time, ideas and hopefully solutions!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `?rasterImage`, or more conveniently in recent versions `image` with option `useRaster = TRUE`.

That will dramatically reduce the size of the file.

```
my.func <- function(x, y) x %*% t(y)
pdf(file="image.pdf")
image(my.func(seq(-10,10,,500), seq(-5,15,,500)), col=heat.colors(100))
dev.off()

pdf(file="rasterImage.pdf")
image(my.func(seq(-10,10,,500), seq(-5,15,,500)), col=heat.colors(100), useRaster = TRUE)
dev.off()

file.info("image.pdf")$size

file.info("rasterImage.pdf")$size
```

image.pdf:   813229 bytes

rasterImage.pdf  16511 bytes

See more details about the new features here:

http://developer.r-project.org/Raster/raster-RFC.html

http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-1/RJournal_2011-1_Murrell.pdf

Comment: Great! Didn't know it could do that.