# R: Bitmap output in PDF

Tags: r, data-visualization

A lot of the time, I find it very useful to output graphics with `pdf()` as it allows me to scroll through pages and observe subtle differences (e.g. the page numbers may correspond to a particular parameter in a simulation).

Sometimes if the plot is quite packed with information, the fact that the PDF is a vector graphic means that it takes a long time to load in a PDF reader and is useless for scrolling through pages. I could plot with `png()`, but this would result in many image files.

My ideal solution would be to have a device that will plot a bitmap graphic (e.g. PNG) to a PDF.

I have read that `cairo_pdf()` outputs to a bitmap *sometimes*? Or I could write something that outputs to PNG, then combines these all together into a PDF?

Any other thoughts? Or does anyone have a solution for this already?

Comment: Check `dev.copy` family of functions, in particular, `dev.copy2pdf()`: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grDevices/html/dev2.html. Also, consider requesting moderators to migrate this question to StackOverflow, as it's really an R question, not a statistics one.

Comment: Does one of the solutions on the following page help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8048984, in particular the solution using `readPNG` from the `png` package helped me once.

Comment: Thanks @Ben, I'll try at some point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: have now added method based on `readPNG()` as suggested in comments above. It's a bit slower (3s vs 9s) and seems to result in slightly larger file sizes than ImageMagick. `rasterImage()` interpolation makes no difference to filesize or timing, but alters the appearance slightly. If it's FALSE, then it looks the same as ImageMagick

I have just come up with the following solution using ImageMagick. It's not perfect, but it seems to work well so far.

```
png2pdf <- function(name=NULL,removepngs=TRUE,method="imagemagick",pnginterpolate=FALSE){
  # Run the png() function with a filename of the form name%03d.png
    # Then the actual plotting functions, e.g. plot(), lines() etc.
    # Then dev.off()
    # Then run png2pdf() and specify the name= argument if other pngs exist in the directory

  # Need to incorporate a way of dealing with non-square plots

    if(is.null(name)){
        names <- list.files(pattern="[.]png")
        name <- unique(sub("[0-9][0-9][0-9][.]png","",names))
        if(length(name)!=1) stop("png2pdf() error: Check filenames")
    }else{
        names <- list.files(pattern=paste0(name,"[0-9][0-9][0-9][.]png"))
    }

    # Can change this to "convert" if it is correctly in the system path
  if(method=="imagemagick"){
    cmd <- c('C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.9.0-Q16\\convert.exe',names,paste0(name,".pdf"))
    system2(cmd[1],cmd[-1])
  }else if(method=="readPNG"){
    library(png)
    pdf(paste0(name,".pdf"))
    par(mar=rep(0,4))
    for(i in 1:length(names)){
      plot(c(0,1),c(0,1),type="n")
      rasterImage(readPNG(names[i]),0,0,1,1,interpolate=pnginterpolate)
    }
    dev.off()
  }
  if(removepngs) file.remove(names)
}
```

Comment: Upvoting this, despite a pure R solution would be more elegant.

Comment: Agree that a pure R solution would be better. Have just come across an alternative way to do this using ghostscript and imagemagick:

[pdfconvert](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lava/functions/pdfconvert) [(source)](https://github.com/cran/lava/blob/master/R/zpdfconvert.R)

Comment: Interesting. But I still would prefer a pure R solution. When/if you will have a chance to look at `dev.copy2pdf()`, which I suggested, please share your opinion on that approach.

Comment: Hi @Alek, I tried `dev.copy2pdf()`, however it creates a vector graphics PDF and there doesn't seem to be any option to create it in bitmap form

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the update. It was just a guess, based on reading the documentation too fast. Your original and referred solutions are good - I simply prefer to not rely on third-party tools. It seems that in this case, that's the only option.