# Can I plot an image to PDF file in R?

Tags: image, r, pdf

Is there a way of loading an image into R and outputting it on pdf?

I know how to plot to pdf and I have tried using the raster and jpeg package but they won't output the image.

The purpose is I am building a PDF pack of charts and want a logo on the page.

Anyone know of another way?

Comment: Does `pdf("filepath/filename.pdf")` redirect output as you want? Close the file with `dev.off()` to view it.

Comment: I would almost say that it is easier to process your pdf after creation with some other program than R and add there then a title page, watermark or logo.

Comment: @DanielFischer there is a certain kick to it, doing everything programmatically. Also, this is very much in the spirit of "Reproducible Research". Imagine the pain of planting those logo's every time you change a graph.

Comment: @Maxim.K Where is the problem, just use a command line tool for that work and everything is easily reproducible. You could even call it from within R using the `system` command, if you want to do so. But of course you are right, it is nice to do as much as possible within one program, but sometimes you will get simply better looking results if you do not squeeze your task into a certain framework, but use specialized programs. This is at least my experience.

Comment: what is the format of your logo? jpeg, png?

Comment: [tutorial example with ggplot2](http://blog.ggplot2.org/post/23537012922/adding-watermarks-to-plots)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with raster for this:

```
library(raster)
r <- brick(file.path(R.home(), "doc", "html", "logo.jpg"))
pdf("a.pdf")
plotRGB(r)
dev.off()
```

Note that if you are going to use image() for large rasters you are best to set useRaster = TRUE (raster does this by default for its objects, or use rasterImage() directly) to avoid really large PDF files.

Comment: Thanks for this, also need the parameter axes=FALSE in the plotRGB function.

Answer (score 3):

I borrow from Matloff's book "The Art of R programming" (p. 63, try Google books):

```
library(pixmap)
logo <- read.pnm("filename") # the file has to be in PPM format
pdf("path/filename.pdf")
plot(logo)
dev.off()
```

Alternatively you can try using `addlogo()` function from the same package, it seems promising for allowing logo coordinates, although I don't have the time to test it thoroughly. You can convert from JPG (or whatever you have) to PPM using one of the online converters.

Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048984/plot-as-bitmap-in-pdf?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597081/combining-vector-and-bitmap-graphics-in-a-pdf) thread, both dealing with similar problems. Answers offered there are much more detailed.

Comment: I tried this and it created a pdf of over 6MB but when I opened it, it just had a blank white page? Any ideas why?

Comment: It worked for me when I tried it (the main option, not addlogo()). Perhaps @DanielFischer was right, easier to use external tools to add the logo/watermark.

Answer (score 0):

Like this -

```
m = matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10)
pdf("image.pdf")
image(m)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `biOps` package from CRAN.

```
# Read image
im = readJpeg('path/to/image')
# Save to pdf
pdf('path/to/pdf')
plot(im)
dev.off();
```

In my experience, this is a little faster than the other packages i've used